# FrameLayout cannot be cast to TextView, weird ClassCastException

Tags: android, textview, classcastexception, android-framelayout

My App throws a weird exception.
The LogCat output says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be converted to  android.widget.TextView.
```

This Exception is caused by this line:

```
TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
```

R.id.distance definitely refers to a TextView and I've got no idea how this Exception can be thrown.
So my question is, whether anyone of you has had a similar problem and knows a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Must be a resource ID conflict, try to clean/build your project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to clean and build your project again. If you're using Eclipse, this things happen from time to time when Eclipse cannot build the resource id's correctly.